# Timeout unicorn, rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4.2.1 app running with Unicorn as app server. 
 I need to provide the user with the ability to download csv data. 
 I'm trying to stream the data, but when the file take too long time than Unicorn timeout and Unicorn will kill this process

Is there any way to solve this problem
 My stream code :

```
private
def render_csv(data)
  set_file_headers()
  set_streaming_headers()

  response.status = 200
  self.response_body = csv_lines(data)
  Rails.logger.debug("end")
end

def set_file_headers
  file_name = "transactions.csv"
  headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
  headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{file_name}\""
end

def set_streaming_headers
  #nginx doc: Setting this to "no" will allow unbuffered responses suitable for Comet and HTTP streaming applications
  headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'

  headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache"
  headers.delete("Content-Length")
end

def csv_lines(data)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    #ideally you'd validate the params, skipping here for brevity
    data.find_each(batch_size: 2000) do |row|
      y << "jhjj"+ "\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use configuration file. Change timeout there. Here is how I do it.

In config/unicorn.rb

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/appname/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"


listen "/tmp/unicorn.appname.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 60 #<<< if you need you can increase it.
```

Then you would start unicorn by

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -E production -c config/unicorn.rb
```